# AngularJS многократное выполнение функции

Tags: angularjs

Доброго времени суток, недавно начал изучение AngularJS, и появился вопрос, почему функция в контроллере

```
$scope.somefunc = function(){
console.log(1);
}
```

При её вызове 1 раз в шаблоне, в отладчике показывает что она вызывалась 20 раз, а не положенный ей 1 раз. Подскажите в какую сторону копать, и в чём здесь может быть проблема?

Код контроллера

```
.controller('ScheduleCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.func = function(){
                console.log(1);
            };
        });
```

Вид

```
<div ng-controller="ScheduleCtrl">
        {{func()}}
        </div>
```

Вот результат:

http://joxi.ru/V2VBJ9Qswb9E2v - красное число в кружочках это число повторений

Comment: Покажите код шаблона, где метод вызываете.

Comment: Отладчик может глючить. Сколько раз присутствует в выводе 1? Необходимо предоставить минимальный код который воспроизводит проблему. В текущем виде эта функция не может вызываться 20 раз. Может у Вас цыкл в шаблоне или шаблон с вызовом подключен в другой шаблон или еще какой цыкл в абсолютно непредсказуемом виде.

Comment: Ответил ниже с кодом.

Comment: @sba, в текущем коде, как минимум 2 раза может вызываться

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Использовать функции для вывода значения во view не рекомендуется, потому что функция в таком случае будет вызываться несколько раз на каждой итерации digest цикла. Как минимум два раза:

1. Получить текущее значение
2. Убедиться, что значение больше не меняется

Почему так происходит:
Когда во *view* прописывается переменная из *scope*, ангуляр добавляет для этой переменной *watcher*.
Чтобы определить надо ли обновить *view* или нет, ангуляр запускает *digest* цикл в котором сверяет значения возвращаемые наблюдателями с сохраненными ранее, если значения изменились продолжает запускать *digest* пока изменения не прекратятся.
Недостаток в таком подходе - если изменилось значение всего одной переменной, то проверяться на неизменность все равно будут все наблюдаемые переменные.

В случае если вместо переменной передается функция, она так же будет вызываться на каждом проходе *digest*, для получения значения, по которому можно будет судить нужно ли обновлять *view* или нет.

Для решения - обычно функцию вызывают в коде контроллера, значение присваивают переменной и используют уже ее во *view*.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, в доке что-то такое [упоминается](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

> The watch listener may change the model, which may trigger other
>   listeners to fire. This is achieved by rerunning the watchers until no
>   changes are detected. The rerun iteration limit is 10 to prevent an
>   infinite loop deadlock.

Слушатель может вызывать других слушателей. Будет продолжаться карусель до тех пор пока не будет ситуации, когда не будет изменений.

И эта штука ограничена 10.

Angular ожидает от вас (и действительно призывает вас), чтобы вы изменяли модель, и дали возможность вьюхе реагировать на изменения, а не наоборот.

Comment: А если мне нужно просто один раз выполнить функцию, получить значение которое она возвращает и просто отобразить?

Comment: @Angus123, тогда вызывайте ее внутри контроллера, либо еще вариант `ng-init` но его не рекомендуется использовать для этих целей

Comment: @Angus123, покажите пример контроллера и шаблона и мы сможем подсказать как лучше